# Reusing a UITableView with different view model types

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, cocoa-touch, swiftui

**Problem:**

I have a particular `UITableView` in my project, and I find myself copying and pasting code from this `UITableView` and using the code for similar screens; this approach to things is really bugging me.

**What I've tried:**

I've tried to find ways round this. For example, I tried using a delegate and a generic, but kept getting errors.

I tried adding the generic declaration to my Coordinator class (see CustomTableView below) init function, however, I just got errors like: `Protocol can only be used as a generic constraint because it has Self or associated type requirements`, so I just moved it back to the struct.

I've thought about just declaring a list of my view models in my `UITableView`'s struct as `@ObservedObject`'s and moving on with my project. However, this seems like an easy way round this which lead me to think it would be the wrong way to solve this issue.

**What am I missing?**

There must be a way I can reuse the same tableView by simply just passing in its associated viewModel and never needing to declare ObservedObjects in the tableView struct.

**I have a protocol that looks like this:**

```
protocol CustomTableViewDelegate: ObservableObject {
    // ...
}
```

All of the closures inside this protocol are basically clones of the `UITableViewDelegates` methods. Why am I doing this? I'm doing this so that any time any of my view models need to use my custom `UITableView`, I can simply conform to this delegate.

**Like what I am doing here in my view model:**

```
class CustomViewModel: ObservableObject, CustomTableViewDelegate {
   // ...
}
```

**This is my custom `UITableView` (I've removed some functions to reduce the code):**

```
struct CustomTableView<T: CustomTableViewDelegate>: UIViewRepresentable {

    var viewModel: T

    class Coordinator: NSObject, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

        var customTableView: CustomTableView

        init(_ customTableView: CustomTableView) {
            self.customTableView = customTableView
        }

        func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
            self.customTableView.viewModel.numberOfSections(in: tableView)
        }

        func makeCoordinator() -> CustomTableView.Coordinator {
            Coordinator(self)
        }

        func makeUIView(context: Context) -> UITableView {
            let coordinator = context.coordinator
            return context.coordinator.customTableView.viewModel.makeUIView(coordinator: coordinator)
        }

        func updateUIView(_ uiView: UITableView, context: Context) {
            context.coordinator.customTableView.viewModel.updateUIView(uiView, coordinator: context.coordinator)
        }
    }
}
```

**In my main view:**

```
struct MyMainView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var customViewModel: CustomViewModel

    var body: some View {

        return

            VStack {
                CustomTableView<CustomViewModel>(viewModel: customViewModel)
            }
    }
}
```

I've tried everything and just seem to keep going in circles. I thought about having one view model that references all of my other view  models, then passing that into my custom table view but I'm not coming to the realisation that  maybe I'm missing something, perhaps my attempts to solve this all had flaws.

So, how can I simply setup my CustomTableView so that it can work with any ViewModel that has an ObservableObject type?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is possible solution. Tested with Xcode 11.4 / iOS 13.4

If you move/duplicate all `UITablView` delegate/datasource callbacks into view model, then actually you don't need context coordinator at all, so generic entities can be as

```
// generic table view model protocol
protocol CustomTableViewModel: UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {
    func configure(tableView: UITableView)
}

// generic table view that depends only on generic view model
struct CustomTableView<ViewModel:ObservableObject & CustomTableViewModel>: UIViewRepresentable {
    @ObservedObject var viewModel: ViewModel

    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> UITableView {
        let tableView = UITableView()
        viewModel.configure(tableView: tableView)
        return tableView
    }

    func updateUIView(_ tableView: UITableView, context: Context) {
        tableView.reloadData()
    }
}
```

And here is example of usage

```
// some specific model
class MyViewModel: NSObject, ObservableObject, CustomTableViewModel {
    let items = ["one", "two", "three"]
    let cellIdentifier = "MyCell"

    func configure(tableView: UITableView) {
        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.dataSource = self
        tableView.register(MyTableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: cellIdentifier)
        tableView.separatorStyle = UITableViewCell.SeparatorStyle.none
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int { items.count }

    func numberOfRows(in section: Int) -> Int { 1 }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! MyTableViewCell
        cell.textLabel?.text = items[indexPath.row]
        return cell
    }
}

struct MyView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var myViewModel: MyViewModel

    var body: some View {
        CustomTableView(viewModel: myViewModel)
    }
}
```

*Note: actually with next decomposition step it could be separation of `Presenter` concept from `ViewModel`, but for simplicity of demo for direction above should be enough.*

Comment: This solved my issue. I can now simply make any of my view models use my protocol. Can you explain why  "& CustomTableViewModel>" was needed in the CustomTableView? I removed that part, and everything still works fine.

Comment: @LondonGuy, I use `configure(tableView:)` from it, you probably don't.

Comment: Just noticed I do use it, but it was actually `ObservableObject &` that I removed because my protocol looks like this protocol `CustomTableViewDelegate: ObservableObject, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {` I will also rename my protocol as I guess that may confuse me in the future.

Answer (score 1):

To be honest it is hard for me to comprehend what are you trying to do.

I believe this error:
**SwiftUI: UIRepresentable view error states a reference to a generic type requires arguments in <...>**

simply means that in this part:

```
  struct CustomTableView<T: CustomTableViewDelegate>: UIViewRepresentable {

    var viewModel: T

    class Coordinator: NSObject, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

      var customTableView: CustomTableView
```

instead of this:

```
var customTableView: CustomTableView
```

you should have something like:

```
var customTableView: CustomTableView<SomeDelagateYouHaveSomewhere>
```

When using generic type just make sure you provide the type to use with it.
Although I really think that is not the real problem here altogether.

Basically what you have there is a class definition inside of the struct that is refering to this struct... Why?
Is it important that this class would be only usable in the scope of this struct?

**What I think you want is simply inheritance of the UITableView class to create your custom one, and then use it or override it whenever needed.**

Also please note the differences between struct and class (like inheritance). You can find some useful info here: https://learnappmaking.com/struct-vs-class-swift-how-to/

This answer my not be exactly what you are looking for, but I hope it can help you to get on the right track.

Comment: Unfortunately, this didn't work for me. What I was trying to do was mentioned in my question and at the end of the description. In short, I wanted to reuse my custom table view, rather than create a new one for each view model. With the accepted answer, I can now use any view model with the single custom table view I created. Thanks for your effort. In the SwiftUI, the Coordinator class is used inside the custom view struct: https://www.hackingwithswift.com/books/ios-swiftui/using-coordinators-to-manage-swiftui-view-controllers

Answer (score 0):

It is actually easier than you'd think. The tableview all cares about is the datasource and doesn't care where it'll come from. Just create a class where you implement UITableViewDataSource and you could also do the same for UITableViewDelegate. Assign the datasource and the delegate to the tableview's datasource and delegate and that's all. You could do that in the composition root from where you instantiate the viewcontroller and get access to the tableview. This is also a nice way to test everything in isolation.

```
class MyDataSource: NSObject, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {
private var dataSource: [String] = []

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return dataSource.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = UITableViewCell(style: .default, reuseIdentifier: "Cell")
    
    return cell
}


func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    // 
}
```

}

And in all you have to do is this:

```
let datasourceProvider = MyDataSource()
let vc = SomeUIViewController()
vc.tableView.datasource = datasourceProvider
vc.tableView.delegate = datasourceProvider
```